# Error renaming JAR from tempDeploy folder to deploy folder

Tags: eclipse, maven, jboss

I keep getting this error while trying to work with PrimeFaces and JBoss together via Maven. I can't find a solution anywhere. Does anybody know what I have to do about this?

> Error renaming C:\Users\dlmai61\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core\JBoss_6.x_Runtime_1_Server1319181703325\tempDeploy\tmp8637101057152747448.jar to C:\Users\dlmai61\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core\JBoss_6.x_Runtime_1_Server1319181703325\deploy\rdtravel-ear.ear\rdtravel-war-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war\WEB-INF\lib\primefaces-3.0.M3.jar.
>
> This may be caused by your server's temporary deploy directory being on a different filesystem than the final destination.
>
> You may adjust these settings in the server editor.

Comment: I don't do Maven, so I can't answer how to do it from the Maven side on, but basically, one of the solutions is to tell Maven to use the JBoss deploy folder.

Comment: Check similar thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26487574/jboss-tools-deploy-error-this-may-be-caused-by-your-servers-temporary-deploy-d/32605175#32605175

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JBoss Tools deploy error: This may be caused by your server's temporary deploy directory being on a different filesystem than the final destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26487574/jboss-tools-deploy-error-this-may-be-caused-by-your-servers-temporary-deploy-d)