# JBoss Tools deploy error: This may be caused by your server's temporary deploy directory being on a different filesystem than the final destination

Tags: java, eclipse, deployment, jboss, jboss-tools

I have the following error when deploying an application with JBoss Tools in Eclipse:

> Error renaming C:\wildfly-8.1.0.Final\standalone\tmp\tmp7858611943756287857.xhtml to C:\wildfly-8.1.0.Final\standalone\deployments\.war\403.xhtml.
>
> This may be caused by your server's temporary deploy directory being on a different filesystem than the final destination.
>
> You may adjust these settings in the server editor.

And here is a screenshot of the error:

[image: JBoss Tools error]

On the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/4.1.x.Final/en/User_Guide/html_single/index.html#Manage_Server_Settings_in_the_Deployment_Tab), I found this:

> You can customize the deployment location and packaging type:
>
> - To select the workspace deployment folder for the server, click *Use workspace metadata*.
> - To select the deployment folder of the application server, click *Use the JBoss deploy folder*.
> - To select a folder of your choice, click *Use a custom deploy folder*. With this option, complete the *Deploy directories* and *Temporary Deploy Directory* fields. **The temporary folder must be on the same file system as the final deploy location otherwise publishing often fails**.
> - For all modules to be archived for deployment, select the *Deploy projects as compressed archives* check box. This avoids exploded
>     deployments and reduces the amount of memory deployments occupy but
>     may result in slower deployment.

What does *The temporary folder must be on the same file system as the final deploy location* mean? How can I solve it?

I've realized that the error doesn't occur when the check box *Deploy projects as compressed* archives is checked.

Comment: I also asked the same question at https://developer.jboss.org/message/907562#907562.

Comment: This issue is being tracked [here](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-18697).

Comment: I honestly never found a solution for this issue in Eclipse, so I ended up switching to IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: this issue is so annoying! it triggers everytime I save

Answer (score 16):

**I solved this problem following the steps below:**

1. Restarted the computer
2. Deleted the project files from the folder "standalone\deployments"
3. Deleted all files in the folder "standalone\tmp"
4. Clean project in Eclipse
5. In Eclipse, removed project from Wildfly and then added again
6. In Eclipse, right click on "Wildfly" and then **"Clean..."**
7. In Eclipse, right click on the project module and then **"Full publish"**

Comment: In my case it worked just by removing the project from server and then cleaning it. Once the server status is synchronized again add the project and start the server. No need to restart the machine.

Comment: Thank's @Vishrant by the additional help. JBoss Tools AS Adapter for Wildfly 11 is making the same trouble and this fix is working well here!

Comment: Great! Deleting the deployments AND tmp contents did the trick to me.

Answer (score 10):

I get this error right after I updated a dependency in my pom.xml and tried to republish.

The thing that worked was to uncheck the setting in the server deployment for "Deploy projects as compressed archives"

[image]

Comment: I believe I've nailed this problem down and observed that it got partially solved between JBoss Developer Studio 8.1.0.GA and 10.0.0.GA. I've also filed https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-22878 to get the rest resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the only solution after hours looking for in google, I solved closing eclipse, deleting the folder ".metadata" of the workspace restarting eclipse and creating the server of JBoss AS 6.x again and deploying again and everything worked for me correctly. I hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem. Files of the `.metadata` and `.recommenders` workspace folders were corrupted. I took those folders from a colleague and replaced mine. It worked!

Answer (score 0):

The hermeslm solution fixes most (if not all) problems with workspace, but it is final and robust weapon of choice. Be advised that if you have highly configured eclipse (custom code assist, formatting definitions, plugins config, UI look) you'll lose it all. You'll have to import all projects and configure it all over again.

I had the same problem but from time to time I do full workspace file-system backup and restore from it when such crap happens.

From what I have observed on backup restore so far, this particular problem may be in configuration jboss server in eclipse and files/plugins related to it. In other words if you don't have backups, **try deleting and rebuilding your servers definition in eclipse** before you'll delete .metadata dir.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to file --> C:\Users\yourusername\wildfly-10.0.0.CR4\standalone\deployments and delete your projectname.war file, server should be able to restart.

Comment: Your answer is at best partial, as it does not clarify why the error occurs in the first place and why deleting the war file should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error message, turns out it was because something went wrong in the deployments folder of JBoss, it wasn't even allowing me to delete my project ear folder from deployments.

My solution was, unzipped another instance of JBoss and pointed my Eclipse to this JBoss and then it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem several times in my windows 10 machine. Since I did not have admin rights it was a hectic process to troubleshoot this issue. Simple fix would be moving JBOSS_HOME closer to root. However, you need to do a proper restart of your eclipse. I rather recommend a complete restart of your computer because after all you are going to change JBOSS_HOME in windows environmental variables.

Answer (score 0):

rather old...but still takes place in NEON version of eclipse and Wildfly. 
and the problem is that Eclipse didn't stop normally the webserver.
(Something very usual for Tomcat at least I do most of the work)
Solution:
I opened the "Debug" presentation. I killed the process.  ( and cleaned-cleared the Server - just in case).

Comment: I honestly never found a solution for this issue in Eclipse, so I ended up switching to IntelliJ IDEA.